# Debugging my NASM x86_64 assembly code and the bug itself

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, nasm

I am currently working through something of an x86_64 crash course which has some very simple examples. Even though the tutorial is said to be 64 bit they use the 32 bit registers, I am following the tutorial with the 64 bit equivalents. I came across the following example program which gives the following output and explains the null terminating byte is missing so the first print string operation assumes the second string variable is part of the first:

INCLUDED FUNCTIONS

```
;      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                       
; int slen(String message)                                                                                                                                                                                  
; String length calculation function                                                                                                                                                                        


slen:                           ; this is our first function declaration                                                                                                                                    

        push    rbx             ; push the value in RBX onto the stack to     preserve it while we use RBX in this function                                                                                     
        mov     rbx, rax        ; move this address in RAX into RBX ( Both   point to the same segment in memory)                                                                                             

nextchar:

    cmp     byte [rax], 0   ; this is the same as lesson 3                                                                                                                                              
    jz      finished
    inc     rax
    jmp     nextchar

finished:

    sub     rax, rbx
    pop     rbx             ; pop the value on the stack back into RBX                                                                                                                                  
    ret                     ; return to where the function was called                                                                                                                                   


    ;; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                        
    ;; void sprint(String message)                                                                                                                                                                      
    ;; String printing function                                                                                                                                                                         
sprint:

    push    rdx
    push    rcx
    push    rbx
    push    rax
    call    slen

    mov     rdx, rax
    pop     rax

    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rbx, 1
    mov     rax, 4
    int     80h

    pop     rbx
    pop     rcx
    pop     rdx

    ;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                      
    ;; void exit()                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ;; Exit program restore resources                                                                                                                                                                   
quit:

    mov     rbx, 0
    mov     rax, 1
    int     80h
    ret
```

MAIN PROGRAM

```
    ;; Hello World Program (Externam file include)                                                                                                                                                      
    ;; Compile with: nasm -f elf64 helloworld-inc.asm                                                                                                                                                   
    ;; Link with ld helloworld-inc.o -o helloworld-inc                                                                                                                                                  
    ;; Run with ./helloworld-inc                                                                                                                                                                        

    %include        'function.asm' ; include our external file                                                                                                                                          

    SECTION .data
    msg1    db      'Hello, brave new world!', 0Ah, 0h              ;our first message string add null terminating byte                                                                                 
    msg2    db      'This is how we recycle in NASM.', 0Ah, 0h      ; our second message string add null terminating byte                                                                               

    SECTION .text
    global _start

_start:

    mov     rax, msg1       ; mov the address of our first message string into RAX                                                                                                                      
    call    sprint          ; call our string printing function                                                                                                                                         

    mov     rax, msg2       ; move the address of our second message string into RAX                                                                                                                    
    call    sprint          ; call our string printing function                                                                                                                                         

    call    quit            ; call our quit function
```

ASSUMED OUTPUT WITH THEIR GIVEN COMMAND

~$ nasm -f elf helloworld-inc.asm 
~$ ld -m elf_i386 helloworld-inc.o -o helloworld-inc 
~$ ./helloworld-inc

```
Hello, brave new world! 
This is how we recycle in NASM. 
This is how we recycle in NASM.
```

MY OUTPUT WITH MY COMMANDS

nasm -f elf64 helloworld-inc.asm 
ld helloworld-inc.o -o helloworld-inc

```
Hello, brave new world!
This is how we recycle in NASM.
```

My output did not include the same issue wherein the lack of a null byte caused the first write operation to use both variables and furthermore when I tested the next program which simply amends the main program as follows I lost the entire "This is how we recycle in NASM." output.

```
SECTION .data
    msg1    db      'Hello, brave new world!', 0Ah, 0h                                                                      
    msg2    db      'This is how we recycle in NASM.', 0Ah, 0h
```

I searched for the answer online and failing in finding an answer I attempted to use gdb to debug the code using the following commands:

nasm -f elf64 -g helloworld-inc.asm
ld helloworld-inc.o -o  hellworld-inc
gdb helloworl-inc

However upon successfully listing the assembly it gives an error when I try to set break points

(gdb) break 17
Cannot access memory at address 0x4000ef

So in summary please explain why the 64 bit registers prevent the need for a null byte and how I can use gdb (or any debugger) to debug my nasm assembly.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. In the first version of the main program the NUL(0( byte is on the end of each string - it isn't missing.

Comment: The reason both lines don't print in your version of the code is because you are missing a `ret` at the bottom of the `sprint` function so it falls through to `exit`. Place a `ret` at the bottom of `sprint` right after `pop rdx`

Comment: I mentioned above about your `ret` issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `break 17` ? Break on line 17.You should be able to `break _start` or `break slen` etc.

Comment: I was trying to set a breakpoint at the line number using the same commands as I did before on a project It now won't let me even list any code. These are the commands:  nasm -f elf64 -g helloworld-if.asm --> ld helloworld-if.o -o hellworld-if

Comment: First I would start by assembling with `nasm -felf64 -g -Fdwarf helloworld-inc.asm`

Comment: Tried it with the ld helloworld-if.o -o helloworld-if command following it and gdb listed no symbols.

Comment: I didn't tell you to modify `ld` command line.I asked you to use a different  NASM command line. Specifically one that adds `-Fdwarf`. This specifies the debug information format to use.

Comment: The reason I used the ld command is that I tried using the .o file in gdb which allowed me to set breakpoints but not to execute it. Yes It has the right permissions. ---  `/bin/bash: /home/benny/x86-64-nasm/helloworld-if.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/bin/bash: /home/benny/x86-64-nasm/helloworld-if.o: Success
During startup program exited with code 126.`

Comment: I didn't tell you NOT to use LD. I simply told you to alter the NASM command line.You keep using your LD command as is. So example: `nasm -felf64 -g -Fdwarf helloworld-inc.asm` `ld helloworld-inc.o -o helloworld-inc`

Comment: Thanks, everything works